# Square matrix over $\mathbb{Z}$ can't have $\frac{1}{4}(-3+ i \sqrt5)$ as an eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials

> Prove square matrix over $\mathbb{Z}$ can't have  $\frac{1}{4}(-3+ i \sqrt5)$ as an eigenvalue.

My proof:

- If matrix has eigenvalue z=$\frac{1}{4}(-3+ i \sqrt5)$, then it must has eigenvalue $\frac{1}{4}(-3- i \sqrt5)$ (conjugate)
- So, the characteristic polynom has form P=$(x-z)(x - \overline z) Q$ , where
  Q - some polynom over $\mathbb{R}$
- $P= a_0x^n + a_1x^{n-1} + a_2x^{n-2}  \dots + a_n$, where $a_0 \dots a_n \in \mathbb{Z}$ (because matrix over $\mathbb{Z}$)
- $Q= q_0x^{n-2} + q_1x^{n-3} + q_2x^{n-4}  \dots + q_{n-2}$, where $q_0 \dots q_n \in \mathbb{R}$
- $(x-z)(x - \overline z) = (x-\frac{1}{4}(-3+ i \sqrt5))* (x-\frac{1}{4}(-3- i \sqrt5)) = x^2 + \frac{3}{2}x + \frac{7}{8}$
- $q_0=1$, otherwise $P$ is not a characteristic polynom($a_0 \neq 1$)
- But if $q_0=1$, then $a_1= \frac{3}{2}$ , **contradiction**

---

Am i right?

Comment: $a_1 = {3 \over 2} + q_1$

Comment: Yes, you are right. Does you have any idea to prove the theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps there's an easier, direct way, but isn't this a matter of using [Gauss' Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomial))?

We use two facts.

1. the product of two primitive polynomials is primitive
2. if $f$ is a non-zero rational polynomial, then $f = \gamma f_{1}$, where $\gamma$ is a rational number, and $f_{1}$ is a primitive polynomial with integer coefficients. The decomposition is unique up to signs

So
$$
f = x^2 + \frac{3}{2}x + \frac{7}{8}
=
\frac{1}{8} (8 x^{2} + 12 x + 7),
$$
where $f_{1} = 8 x^{2} + 12 x + 7$ is primitive, and $\gamma= 1/8$.

Now note that $Q$ has rational coefficients. (You obtain it by dividing $P$ by  $x^2 + \frac{3}{2}x + \frac{7}{8}$.)

Write $Q = \delta Q_{1}$ as above, then
$$
P = \gamma \delta f_{1} Q_{1},
$$
where $f_{1} Q_{1}$ has integer coefficients and it is primitive, and thus by uniqueness $\gamma \delta = \pm 1$, so that $\delta = \pm 8$, so that $8$ divides $q_{0}$.

Comment: Thanks! I did't know Gauss' Lemma. One question: why Q must has rational coefficients?

Comment: You're welcome. As to $Q$, it is probably simpler than this, however: divide $P$ by $f = x^2 + \frac{3}{2}x + \frac{7}{8}$ to get $P = f Q + r$, with $Q, r$ with rational coefficients, and $r$ either 0, or of degree at most $1$. But clearly $r$ has two distinct roots $z, \bar{z}$, so it cannot have degree $0$ or $1$, so $r = 0$.